# CloudKit server-to-server auth + security roles

Tags: cloudkit, server-to-server

Is it possible to use security roles with server-to-server authentication in CloudKit? I would like only my server code to be able to create records in the public database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system role 'Authenticated' and set its permission to "write/read" on the record type you want to lock down.
Your server to server key will still be able to create records of this type.

Comment: Interesting. I can't test this right now since S2S auth seems to be broken for me ATM, but why does Authenticated need write permissions for an S2S key to be able to *create* records? I don't actually want regular users to be able to write to these records.

Comment: Or were you just saying that S2S keys will be able to create records no matter the permissions? Either way, in my testing I can't get CloudKit to accept my "create record" request unless I give `create` permissions to `Authenticated`.